# How to deserialize xml elements that have different names, but the same set of attributes to a typed array/collection

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

This is a part of XML file I'm trying to de-serialize:

```
<entry>
...
<A:family type="user">
 <A:variationCount>7</A:variationCount>
 <A:part type="user">
    <title>94 LPS</title>
    <Voltage type="custom" typeOfParameter="Electrical Potential" units="V">120 V</Voltage>
    <Unit_Length displayName="Unit Length" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Length" units="mm">540</Unit_Length>
    <Unit_Height displayName="Unit Height" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Length" units="mm">222</Unit_Height>
    <Total_Cooling_Capacity displayName="Total Cooling Capacity" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Power" units="W">1758 W</Total_Cooling_Capacity>
    <Supply_Air_Width displayName="Supply Air Width" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Duct Size" units="mm">400 mm</Supply_Air_Width>
    <Supply_Air_Height displayName="Supply Air Height" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Duct Size" units="mm">150 mm</Supply_Air_Height>
    <Sensible_Cooling_Capacity displayName="Sensible Cooling Capacity" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Power" units="W">1348 W</Sensible_Cooling_Capacity>
    <Return_Air_Width displayName="Return Air Width" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Duct Size" units="mm">475 mm</Return_Air_Width>
    <Number_of_Poles displayName="Number of Poles" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Number of Poles">1</Number_of_Poles>
    <Load_Classification displayName="Load Classification" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Load Classification">Cooling</Load_Classification>
    <CFU_Material displayName="CFU Material" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Material">&lt;By Category&gt;</CFU_Material>
    <C2_Offset_1 displayName="C2 Offset 1" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Length" units="mm">108</C2_Offset_1>
    <C1_Offset_1 displayName="C1 Offset 1" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Length" units="mm">108</C1_Offset_1>
    <Apparent_Load displayName="Apparent Load" type="custom" typeOfParameter="Apparent Power" units="VA">50 VA</Apparent_Load>
 </A:part>
 <A:part type="user">
    ...
 </A:part>
 ...
</A:family>
</entry>
```

These are classes I'm using to de-serialize it:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot("entry", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class PartAtom
{
    ...
    [XmlElement("family", Namespace="urn:schemas-autodesk-com:partatom")]
    public Family Family { get; set; }
}

public class Family
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("variationCount")]
    public int VariationCount { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("part")]
    public FamilyType[] Parts { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class FamilyType 
{   
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlArray]
    public Parameter[] Parameters { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public struct Parameter
{
    [XmlAttribute("displayName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("typeOfParameter")]
    public string DataType { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("units")]
    public string Units { get; set; }
}
```

I want the elements such as Voltage, Units_Length, Unit_Height, ... Apparent_Load etc to be de-serialized as instances of Parameters class.
How can I accomplish something like that? Is it even possible?

**UPDATE:**

The parameters (XML elements below the title) are virtually infinite, so I can't contemplate all of them, so all the algorithms where I have to specify XmlElement names manually are unusable.

Comment: Using only attributes to this form, I don't think so.  `Parameter` requires a name, it won't be able to deserialize from elements with multiple names.  You would need a class per parameter type.  If it has to be in this form, consider implementing `IXmlSerializable`.

Comment: @Charles Mager 
> You would need a class per parameter type"
yes, that would be the major problem, but since those parameters are created by users I can't contemplate all of them, so this strategy is a no go.
On another hand implementing `IXmlSerializable` is really annoying, because by default it won't fill "known" elements, event if I leave XmlAttribute/XmlText attributes. Do you know how to avoid this behavior? I mean that `Name`, `DataType`, `Units` etc are not filled automatically and presumably I have to initialize them from `ReadXml` method too :(

Comment: Inside `ReadXml()`, you can load into an `XElement` and deserialize using a nested `XmlSerializer`, along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769495/how-to-derive-xml-element-name-from-an-attribute-value-of-a-class-using-annotati

Comment: Your root element `<entry>` must have a couple of namespaces like so, right?  `<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:A="urn:schemas-autodesk-com:partatom">`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to implement `IXmlSerializable` on your class, one option would be to add a proxy property of `XElement []` elements marked with [`[XmlAnyElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx) and serialize the parameters from and to this list, fixing the names as required.

Assuming your XML has namespace declarations on the root element like the following that were omitted from the question:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:A="urn:schemas-autodesk-com:partatom">
```

Then the following should work:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class FamilyType
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Parameter[] Parameters { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XElement[] XmlParameters
    {
        get
        {
            return XmlKeyValueListHelper.SerializeAttributeNameValueList(Parameters, "name");
        }
        set
        {
            Parameters = XmlKeyValueListHelper.DeserializeAttributeNameValueList<Parameter>(value, "name");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the serializer automatically deserializes the `Title` and `Type` properties rather than passing then to the `AnyElement` array.  Then, in `Parameter`, I changed `Name` to `DisplayName` and added an `ElementName` property to hold the element name:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public struct Parameter
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string ElementName { get; set; } // Added property.

    [XmlAttribute("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } // Changed from Name to DisplayName

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("typeOfParameter")]
    public string DataType { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("units")]
    public string Units { get; set; }
}
```

Using the extension and helper methods:

```
public static class XmlKeyValueListHelper
{
    public static XElement[] SerializeAttributeNameValueList<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string nameAttributeName)
    {
        if (items == null)
            return null;
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", typeof(T).RootXmlElementNamespace());
        var query = items
            .Select(p => p.SerializeToXElement(ns))
            .Select(e =>
            {
                var attr = e.Attribute(nameAttributeName);
                e.Name = e.Name.Namespace + XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName((string)attr);
                attr.Remove();
                return e;
            });
        return query.ToArray();
    }

    public static T[] DeserializeAttributeNameValueList<T>(IEnumerable<XElement> elements, string nameAttributeName)
    {
        if (elements == null)
            return null;
        var query = elements
            .Select(e => new XElement(e)) // Do not modify the input values.
            .Select(e =>
            {
                e.Add(new XAttribute(nameAttributeName, XmlConvert.DecodeName(e.Name.LocalName)));
                e.Name = e.Name.Namespace + typeof(T).RootXmlElementName();
                return e;
            })
            .Select(e => e.Deserialize<T>());
        return query.ToArray();
    }
}

public static class XmlTypeExtensions
{
    public static string RootXmlElementName(this Type type)
    {
        var xmlRoot = type.GetCustomAttribute<XmlRootAttribute>();
        if (xmlRoot != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlRoot.ElementName))
            return xmlRoot.ElementName;
        return type.Name;
    }

    public static string RootXmlElementNamespace(this Type type)
    {
        var xmlRoot = type.GetCustomAttribute<XmlRootAttribute>();
        if (xmlRoot != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlRoot.Namespace))
            return xmlRoot.Namespace;
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    static XmlSerializerNamespaces NoStandardXmlNamespaces()
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
        return ns;
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return obj.SerializeToXElement(null, NoStandardXmlNamespaces());
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        return obj.SerializeToXElement(null, ns);
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        var element = doc.Root;
        if (element != null)
            element.Remove();
        return element;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element)
    {
        return element.Deserialize<T>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)));
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element, XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            object result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Still, easier than a custom `IXmlSerializable`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be multiple `XmlElementAttribute` with different names specified.Something like this:

```
 [XmlElement("Voltage")]
 [XmlElement("Unit_Height")]
 [XmlElement("Supply_Air_Height")]
 [XmlElement("CFU_Material")]
```

Comment: OK, I have to update my question, telling that I don't have an enumeration of all the parameters (Voltage, Unit_Height etc). Virtually they are infinite. So as I already said "I can't contemplate all of them, so this strategy is a no go".

Comment: Do you have any control over the structure of the xml?

Comment: if by "control" you mean the way the data is written to XML - no, I don't have that kind of control. This XML is produced by Autodesk Revit application and most of the parameters are handcrafted.
There is a way to read them from inside the application via Revit APIs, but I need to do it from "outside", so I have to write my own de-serializer.

Comment: Then preprocessing seems to be the most effective way to me. Is it possible to take all the children of `<A:part type="user">` and rename them to `MyFancyElement` before deserializing?

Comment: This is exactly what @Culme suggested.
Anyway the first sub-element of part tag is `title` and there might be others, so the only way to determine whenever an element is a parameter is if it has certain attribs. Additionally sometimes `displayName` attribute is empty so I have to use XMLElement name instead. I've ended up with a semi-automatic parsing solution. I will try to make it even more elegant and will post it here as answer.
Hoping someone will come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

One (ugly) way of doing it, could be to modify the XML before you de-serialize it. Just string-replace all of the "Voltage", "Unit_height" etc with "YourParameterClassName". Then they should all nicely deserialize, and I'm guessing that your "typeOfParameter" will still provide you with the same information that originally was present in the nodes before the replacement.