# C# & Serialization: there are any possible that ElementName of XmlArrayItem decide by the object member value?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have two serializable objects:

```
[Serializable]
public class A
{
    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem]
    public UnitItem[] Items{get;set;}

    ......
}

[Serializable]
public class UnitItem
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

I can serialize A like:

```
<Items>
   <UnitItem Name="AAA">balabala</UnitItem>
   <UnitItem Name="BBB">bulubulu</UnitItem>
   ......
</Items>
```

but now I want to create a XML structure as follows:

```
<Items>
    <AAA>balabala</AAA>
    <BBB>bulubulu</BBB>
   ......
</Items>
```

that is to say **i expected the `ElementName` of `XmlArrayItem` is member variable's value not variable's name**.  How can i do ?

If i have to inherit `ISerializable` could you tell me how to implement it?

Comment: It looks like you can find answer to your question here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You would need to implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for instance as is shown in [how to derive xml element name from an attribute value of a class using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769495/).  But it's a nuisance, so I don't recommend bothering to do it.

Comment: I don't think `Serializable` has anything to do with XML serialization. For XML, you need to mark your class as `XmlRoot`, something like that