# Serialize a C# object to a custom XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Is it possible to serialize a C# object to an XML file with this special format?

```
class Job
{
    Guid         JobGuid;
    List<Source> Sources; 
}
```

I want to get this XML format:
`Module_n` (with n the index of the sub-element) instead of Source

```
<job JobGuid="....."> 
  <Sources>
    <Module_1> </Module_1>
    <Module_2> </Module_2>
  </Sources>
</job>
```

Comment: But not easy.  For `jobGuid` just add `[XmlAttribute("JobGuid")]` to the `JobGuid` property.  But getting the required list element names means you will have to implement `IXmlSerializable`, which is quite burdensome.   To get started see [How do you deserialize XML with dynamic element names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37255149/3744182) and [how to derive xml element name from an attribute value of a class using annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28770138/3744182).  But this XML is poorly designed since it cannot have a proper XSD.  Do you have freedom to change the format?

Comment: Also, make the class `Job` and the properties `JobGuid` and `Sources` public.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have to respect this format. I would like to build a API that do the same thing as the original API.